# 7 Divs, how to make they stay where the picture say?

Tags: html, css

[alt text http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/9776/dviswheretogo.png](http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/9776/dviswheretogo.png)

Blue is where the image of the corners will go

Green is a repeating image on the x axis on the top, all part of the same template!

And orange is a simgle image repeating on the y axis

For clarification here is what I've tried so far, i'm angry about this because when I use relative position it breaks because of an  with background that is above! Anyway I need to define a height and width for each item!

```
    .sheet {position:relative;
    top:140px;
    width:1000px;}

    .tl {
    background:url(../images/sheet_top_left-trans.png) no-repeat;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;}

    .tm {
    background:url(../images/sheet_top-trans.png) repeat-x;
    width:960px;
    height:20px;}

    .tr {
    background:url(../images/sheet_top_right-trans.png) no-repeat;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;}

    .content {
    background:url(../images/sheet_middle.png) repeat-y;
    top:20px;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;}/* Demonstration only, please remove later */

    .bl {
    background:url(../images/sheet_bottom_left-trans.png) no-repeat;
    width:20px;
    height:30px;}

    .bm {
    background:url(../images/sheet_bottom-trans.png) repeat-x;
    height:30px;
    width:960px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:20px;}

    .br {}
```

and the html

```
        <div class="sheet"><!-- Glass Effect Starts here -->

        <div class="tl"></div>
        <div class="tm"></div>
        <div class="tr"></div>
          <div class="content">Here we go again</div>
        <div class="bl"></div>
        <div class="bm"></div>
        <div class="br"></div>
```

If I use absolute postitioning I can't make the bottom images stick to it! tho it works at the top!

**Now I've found I way to do it that is cross-browser (even IE6 just don't use transparent PNG as I did) here we go:**

HTML:

```
    <div class="sheet">

      <div class="top_sheet">
        <div class="tl"></div>
        <div class="tm"></div>
        <div class="tr"></div>
      </div>

        <div class="middle">.</div>

      <div class="bottom_sheet">
        <div class="bl"></div>
        <div class="bm"></div>
        <div class="br"></div>
      </div>


    </div><!-- End of the sheet class -->
```

CSS:

```
.sheet {position:relative;
width:1000px;
top:10px;}

.top_sheet {width:1000px;
height:20px;}

.tl {float:left;
background:url(../images/sheet_top_left-trans.png) no-repeat;
height:20px;
width:20px;}

.tm {float:left;
background:url(../images/sheet_top-trans.png) repeat-x;
height:20px;
width:960px;}

.tr {float:right;
background:url(../images/sheet_top_right-trans.png) no-repeat;
height:20px;
width:20px;}

.middle {position:relative;
background: url(../images/sheet_middle.png) repeat-y;
width:1000px;
height:400px;}

bottom_sheet {width:1000px;
height:30px;}

.bl {float:left;
background:url(../images/sheet_bottom_left-trans.png) no-repeat;
width:20px;
height:30px;}

.bm {float:left;
background:url(../images/sheet_bottom-trans.png) repeat-x;
width:960px;
height:30px;}

.br {float:right;
background:url(../images/sheet_bottom_right-trans.png) no-repeat;
width:20px;
height:30px;}
```

Comment: Is there no closing tag for `<div class='sheet'>` ?

Comment: I realize this might be HTML4 or HTML5, but if its not, that could cause a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to put in there but yes there is a closing tag I try to make it all W3C standard!

Comment: It might take a while for me to decide what is the best answer! There is one that points to a website that looks like a book, hehehe, not complaining, if it works I will be grateful forever! just saying I have to deconstruct my own work a few times here to test all of the solutions! thank you all!

Comment: I'm almost doing it, when it's finished and cross-browser I'll post the code, I would like to thank you all, because some ideas here were/are great!

Comment: I've create a class for the top of the sheet (with all the top divs inside) and a class fot the bottom (all the bottom divs inside) and then I used float:left on .tl .tm and float:right on the .tr the same at the bottom (left left right), ok just look at the code!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to use the same html you already have, here is something that seems to work pretty well.

Move the corners into an all encompassing top and bottom bar. And then float the respective corners left and right.

CSS:

```
.sheet {
    position:relative;
    width:1000px;
    top:140px;}
.tl {
    background:url(images/sheet_top_left-trans.png) no-repeat;
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin-left:-20px;}
.tm {
    background:url(images/sheet_top-trans.png) repeat-x;
    height:20px;
    margin-left:20px;}
.tr {
    background:url(images/sheet_top_right-trans.png) no-repeat;
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;}
.content {
    background:url(images/sheet_content.png) repeat-y;
    clear:both;
    height:200px;}/* Demonstration only, please remove later */
.bl {
    background:url(images/sheet_bottom_left-trans.png) no-repeat;
    float:left;
    width:20px;
    height:30px;}
.bm {
    background:url(images/sheet_bottom-trans.png) repeat-x;
    height:30px;}
.br {
    background:url(images/sheet_bottom_right-trans.png) no-repeat;
    float:right;
    width:20px;
    height:30px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sheet"><!-- Glass Effect Starts here -->
    <div class="tm">
        <div class="tl"></div>
        <div class="tr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">Here we go again</div>
    <div class="bm">
        <div class="bl"></div>
        <div class="br"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will not the top middle background overlap upon the others? it is using PNG with transparence to give a glass effect, any way I'll try it!

Comment: Your right, it will. I tested it out on the top, and it displays behind the top-left, but not the top-right

Comment: The fix for that on my test sheet was to add a margin-left: 20px on  .tm and then add margin-left:-20px on .tl

Comment: Sorry - semi-new to the stackoverflow - I updated the css up top to reflect those changes.

Comment: Don't worry! I'm new to CSS! hehe, it seems that this is the only thing I can't do for now! even tho I have no intension of making this compatible with IE6 only with IE7 and IE8!

Comment: Not exactly how I got there but your answer was the one that give me the idea so I'm choosing it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some cross-browser css framework, e.g. [http://www.blueprintcss.org](http://www.blueprintcss.org/)?
These frameworks usually let you define **grids** and will help you to overcome browser-specific quirks by resetting certain css properties ...

Comment: No, I have not, I'll check into it, but I really need some help with this one none the less thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Fluid width containers with rounded corners using valid CSS and XHTML](http://blog.josh420.com/archives/2007/11/how-to-create-fluid-width-div-layers-with-rounded-corners.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The method I usually see is nesting all the divs to layer them, then setting the `background-repeat` and `background-position` on each one. Basic example:

```
<div class="tl">
<div class="tr">
    <div class="content">Here we go again</div>
</div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.tl, .tr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tl {
    background: url("tl.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}
.tr {
    background: url("tr.png") no-repeat 100% 0;
}
```

Simply scale that up to use all your separate images. You'll need to have the sides first (on the outside of the 'div nest') and the corners last (on the inside, right before the content div).

It's a classic case of "divitis", but it's hard to avoid until CSS3 is well supported (where you can use multiple backgrounds or simply a border image). You might was to check out [Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/), which shows a technique for reducing the number of elements/images needed.

Comment: It means that all divs will be 100% all directions and I'll just positions the backgrounds right? so the order is: top, right, bottom, left, (clockwise), if I'm not mistaken, hehe, I think background positioning is not remotely suported by IE6 (I don't really care), I'll try this one, and play around with these settings! thank you

Comment: the 100% height doesn't work on this divs, I'm playing now with another idea that seems to be working for every browser, using floats inside divs, left left and right, anyway I still wanna try this later on another template

Comment: Background positioning works fine in IE6. I'm not sure if you're misunderstanding about the divs, the 100% height should work fine, but the "clockwise" thing you mentioned doesn't make sense. You only have one background per div. The order I recommended in my answer is to just do the corners after the edges to layer them on top.

Answer (score 0):

css:
    .sheet {
        position:relative;
        top:140px;
        width:1000px;
        }

```
    .tl {
    background:url(blue.bmp) no-repeat;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    }

    .tm {
    position: absolute;
    background:url(green.bmp) repeat-x;
    width:960px;
    height:20px;
    left: 20px;
    top: 0px;
    }

    .tr {
    position: absolute;
    background:url(blue.bmp) no-repeat;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    }

    .content {
    background:url(orange.bmp) repeat-y;
    top:20px;
    width:1000px;
    height:400px;}/* Demonstration only, please remove later */

    .bl {
    background:url(blue.bmp) no-repeat;
    width:20px;
    height:30px;}

    .bm {
    position: absolute;
    background:url(green.bmp) repeat-x;
    height:30px;
    width:960px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:20px;}

    .br {
        position: absolute;
        background:url(blue.bmp) no-repeat;
        width:20px;
        height:30px;
        top:420px;
        right:0px;
    }

  html:
<div class="sheet"><!-- Glass Effect Starts here -->

    <div class="tl"></div>
    <div class="tm"></div>
    <div class="tr"></div>
      <div class="content">Here we go again</div>
    <div class="bl"></div>
    <div class="bm"></div>
    <div class="br"></div>
```

I put absolute positioning on each divs so that we can position it side by side. Hope it helps.
BTW, I changed the background url. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Winks as he says this and may regret it:*

You know, if you used a table... ;>P!

(Now, waits for the tables vs. css crowd to unleash!)

This looks like your regular, garden-variety rounded corners 'section'.

Here's one without images:

http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html

Here's one with:

http://kalsey.com/2003/07/rounded_corners_in_css/

When you're finished coding it and it looks like what you want, turn it into a code snippet and keep it.

Comment: I'll give it a try, I thought about tabs, would be so easy in comparison to divs! but you know they will not work forever... I hope CSS3 become a standard soon!

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be a smartarse, but you hardly need 7 divs for what you try to achieve. Five divs are enough (in most case you don't even need that. I really don't know how to explain, but you can check http://www.nil.com/english (**Quick links** or **Get support** boxes) for source.

Also, there is a great book about it called ["Bulletproof web design"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321509021)

Comment: I'm tring to achieve a glass effect using 7 png files with transparence not only rounded corners! so since I'm not using background color and only images for a width that will vary in the future it a little bit more tricky!

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You yet have to `position` the containing element `relative` (so that all `absolute` positioned child elements are relative to it) and to `position` the corner parts `absolute`. Here's a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 1898479</title>
        <style>
        .sheet {
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
        }

        .tl {
            position: absolute;
            width:20px;
            height:20px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: blue;
        }

        .tm {
            position: absolute;
            height:20px;
            top: 0;
            left: 20px;
            right: 20px;
            background: green;
        }

        .tr {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: blue;
        }

        .content {
            background: orange;
            padding: 20px 0; /* Padding must be at least as much as the "borders" are thick. */
            height: 300px;
        }

        .bl {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background: blue;
        }

        .bm {
            position: absolute;
            height: 20px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 20px;
            right: 20px;
            background: green;
        }

        .br {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            background: blue;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="sheet">
            <div class="tl"></div>
            <div class="tm"></div>
            <div class="tr"></div>
            <div class="content">Here we go again</div>
            <div class="bl"></div>
            <div class="bm"></div>
            <div class="br"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You only need to ensure that you're using the [**strict** doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) as used in the above example so that it works in IE as well.

Comment: strict doctype and joomla don't go well! but I'll create a completelly diferent template for IE6 and use a javascript to select the right one for the right browser

Comment: I've never used it but I'd really expect Joomla to be a bit more robust. It does not adhere the web standards? The horror! I wish you much luck with that.

Comment: well, the new version "1.6" is supposed to be tableless! but even the current version validates well, but it is kinda messy, the classes for menu itens change dynamically... but I do like Joomla and Wordpress!